# exporting clustering result from R to matlab

Tags: r, matlab, cluster-analysis

I ran a clustering algorithm on R:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(data),method=”complete”)
```

I want to export this result to matlab (like the result of linkage) in order to compute the insconsistency. Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't matlab already have hierarchical clustering, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation of `hclust`,  `hc$merge` gives the indices used to create clusters and `hc$height` gives the distance between the indices.

With USArrests as sample dataset:

```
hc<- hclust(dist(USArrests), method="complete")

data.mat<-data.matrix(data.frame(hc$merge,hc$height))
> head(data.mat)
      X1  X2 hc.height
[1,] -15 -29  2.291288
[2,] -17 -26  3.834058
[3,] -14 -16  3.929377
[4,] -13 -32  6.236986
[5,] -35 -44  6.637771
[6,] -36 -46  7.355270)

write.csv(data.mat,"data_mat.csv",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
```

and in matlab after reading data into say matrix Z, the following will give the inconsistency in linkages

```
incons.Z = inconsistent(Z)
```

**OR**

You could compute inconsistency in R using `scale` function, which subtracts `mean` of all observations from the current observation and divides it by std. deviation (`sd`) i.e. normalizes it.

```
inconsis_scale<-as.vector(scale(data.mat[,3]))
```

alternately, using functions `mean` and `sd`:

```
inconsis_base<-(data.mat[,3]-mean(data.mat[,3]))/sd(data.mat[,3])
```

the two approaches yield same results which can be confirmed by

```
> all.equal(inconsis_scale,inconsis_base)
[1] TRUE
```